# No memory avaiable on my Galaxy S4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, insufficient-memory

I don't understand why I can't take photo or video with my Samsung Galaxy S4. I have 32 GB of memory and I haven't a lot of photo or apps in my mobile phone. I tried to delete photo, video or apps that I don't use, and also I have just restart my phone but the situation is the same.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! That's a quite extensive area. To narrow down your issue (and give you some background), may I suggest you consult our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](/tags/insufficient-memory/info), and follow its first-aid instructions as well as links? That done, please come back here and [edit] your post with specific details, including what you've tried and where you're stuck. Wish you quick success! :)

Comment: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking with experiance with a galaxy S4.

> Try deleting the cache, from the storage menu.
>   Goto Storage->Internal Storage-> Delete Cache

Should empty up a lot of space by now, for more storage,

> Goto Storage->Internal Storage-> Explore

Delete files named,

- .thumbnails
- .profigos
- .faces

These are temporary files created, you can delete them, it won't harm any of your data.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I realized my Dropbox was taking up a lot of space.   I had my photos etc already downloaded do I just disabled it and now I have a lot more space.   Hope this helps.